GNOME OS NIGHTLY I zoomed in and now I can’t zoom out (cant use keyboard)
My keyboard died a few days ago and I started using screen keyboard. However I pressed on the "zoom in" button and I can't zoom out.
I've tried restarting my pc multiple times, however even after restart I remained zoomed in. My mouse is not visible and sadly shortcuts don't work since my keyboard is dead. I'm pretty sure this isn't a bug, perhaps people were never meant to use the OS without a keyboard.
More info:

I'm using Gnome OS Nightly (I think 40)
I remain zoomed in, even at the login screen.
Whenever I use the scroll wheel the mouse flickers and then disappears again.
I activated zoom by pressing the icon on the top right, it's located near the Wi-Fi and it opens a menu with options like: contrast, virtual keyboard and zoom.

I contacted info@gnome.org

Please [edit] and give us some context. What on screen keyboard is this? What zoom button? Do you still see this button? Do you still see the keyboard? Can you try Ctr+0, does that help? Have you logged out? Have you restarted?

does this happen on a released version as well? If you find a bug in a version that is a "nightly" development version, then that's expected; that's why it's called "nightly" and not a supported release. It only exists for bugs to be found, so if you find bugs: great! Communicate them with the developers. That's why you'd install a nightly version. If you just want to use something, don't install a nightly version, unless a developer explains to you why (such cases happen,like you needing bugfix that is not yet in a released version; in general, nightlies are not for public consumption.)

In any case, this sounds like something you need to discuss with the GNOME project developers, not really us; chances are, none of us use the same experimental version with the same bugs as you, and even if someone did, they would very likely go and ask you to fill in a bug report :)

I can’t see the keyboard and the button to activate/disable zoom, I’m not able to interact with the menu.

I’ve tried restarting my pc multiple times, however even after restart I remained zoomed in, my mouse is not visible and sadly shortcuts dont work since my keyboard is dead. I’m pretty sure this isn’t a bug, perhaps people where never meant to use the OS without a keyboard. More info:

I’m using Gnome OS Nightly (I think 40), I remain zoomed in, even at the login screen, whenever I use the scroll wheel the mouse flickers and then disappears again. I activated zoom by pressing the icon on the top right, it’s located near the wifi and it opens a menu with options like: contrast, virtual keyboard and zoom.
